# Scene refresh frozen

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glut

I render the 2D (tiles-based) scene and register keypresses. When arrow keys are pressed I move the camera. Although keypresses are registered just fine, **my scene does not update until I swap to another window and go back**.

Can you give me a clue about what is causing the problem?

PS. I'm working on *Linux*, developing *OpenGL* application with a help of *glut* (*freeglut*).

My rendering function:

```
void render() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    if (s_map)
    for (int i = s_iCameraX; i < sc_iTilesY + s_iCameraY && i < s_map->usiHeight; i++)
    {
        for (int j = s_iCameraY; j < sc_iTilesX + s_iCameraX && j < s_map->usiWidth; j++)
        {
            short val = s_map->data[i][j];              
            if (val == 0x0010) glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
            else if (val == 0x0020) glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f(j-s_iCameraX, i-s_iCameraY);
                glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f(j-s_iCameraX+1.0f, i-s_iCameraY);
                glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f(j-s_iCameraX+1.0f, i-s_iCameraY+1.0f);
                glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f(j-s_iCameraX, i-s_iCameraY+1.0f);
            glEnd();
        }
    }

glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

My special key processing function:

```
void keyproc(int key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key)
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        printf("UP: %d %d\n", s_iCameraX, s_iCameraY);
        if (s_iCameraY - 1 >= 0) s_iCameraY--;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        printf("DOWN: %d %d\n", s_iCameraX, s_iCameraY);
        if (s_map && s_iCameraY + 1 < s_map->usiHeight) s_iCameraY++;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        printf("RIGHT: %d %d\n", s_iCameraX, s_iCameraY);
        if (s_map && s_iCameraX + 1 < s_map->usiWidth) s_iCameraX++;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        printf("LEFT: %d %d\n", s_iCameraX, s_iCameraY);
        if (s_iCameraX - 1 >= 0) s_iCameraX--;
        break;

    default: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your main loop ?

Comment: I don't have one. I make use of glut `glutMainLoop()` function.

Comment: Is `render()` still called after pressing a key (you can trace it with `printf()` ? What is your idle callback ?

Comment: render() is called after pressing a key and switching a window (if I understood you well) and I don't have IDLE callback. Is it a must-have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might be worth a try: add an idle callback:

```
void idle(void)
{
    // Force GLUT to render the scene
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```